# Group By set value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table which shows the duration of visits for users in minutes. I am looking to group the minutes value - in buckets which increment by 10, and count the number of  items in each bucket like so:

```
duration(minutes)  count
0                  20
10                 400
20                 1400
30                 100
```

All the way to the maximum minute value. The values shown for the duration buckets represents the upper value of the bucket, so it really is something like this:

```
duration(minutes)      count
0 - 10                 20
11 - 20                400
21 - 30                1400
31 - 40                100
etc
```

Not sure how to setup the mysql query for this.

Comment: I updated my answer with your updated ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can always group on the result of a calculation, in this case, something like this would be appropriate:

```
SELECT 10 * ((mins-1) DIV 10) AS groupVal, COUNT(*)
FROM theTable
GROUP BY groupVal
;
```

However, your ranges are slightly ambiguous, as 0-10 overlaps 10-20 overlaps 20-30 and so on. The grouping intent might be clearer in the query like so...

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN mins >= 0 AND mins <= 10 THEN 0 
   WHEN mins > 10 AND mins <= 20 THEN 10 
   WHEN mins > 20 AND mins <= 30 THEN 20 
   WHEN mins > 30 AND mins <= 40 THEN 30 
   ELSE -1
   END AS groupVal
, COUNT(*)
FROM theTable
GROUP BY groupVal
;
```

These should work in MySQL; if you are using MS SQL you cannot use the alias, groupVal, in the `GROUP BY` clause and will instead need to clone the calculation in the first example or entire `CASE ... END` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

you can divide and then rounding the result

```
SELECT  TRUNCATE(duration / 10, 0) * 10 as duration(minutes), count(*) as `count`
FROM table
GROUP BY  TRUNCATE(duration / 10, 0)
;
```

Comment: how do the ranges look like with this method? do they overlap? ( like the comment below points out?). I edited my original question to show how the ranges should look like.

Comment: @user2022284 this answers ranges are `0 is 0-9`, `10 is 10 to 19`, and so on. Also, the `duration(minutes)` alias probably needs escaped to prevent parsing problems.